# How to pull a value out of a parentheses

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list:

```
[(1,3),(2,4)]
```

How can I pull just the values 1 and 2 from both the elements from the list. to my knowledge I cannot index as the values are in parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would give this list a name, something like:

```
pairs_list = [(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Then you can access them using the indices. So:

```
print(pairs_list[0][0])
print(pairs_list[1][0])
```

Basically what's happening here is you want to access the first pair, at 0th index, and the first number, at that pair's 0th index. Then the second list, at the 1st index, and its first number, at the 0th index.

Or as the other commenter suggested, you can assign these values to a variable and print the variables. Like:

```
first_num = pairs_list[0][0]
second_num = pairs_list[1][0]
```

Then you just print those two variables.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to read some basic documentation / tutorials about python, in particular about lists and tuples. (see links at the end of my answer)

If

```
l = [(1,3),(2,4)]
```

then `l` is a `list` with two members, each  member is a `tuple` with two members.

You can get the `1` with `l[0][0]` and the `2` with `l[1][0]`

`l[0]` would yield the tuple `(1, 3)`

if you want to get the `1` and the `2` in one line you might look at the documentation of the `zip` function.

`one, two = next(zip(*l))`

or you do it explicitly with:

`one, two = l[0][0], l[1][0]`

Relevant links:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: *Links* to the documentation would make this a much better answer

Comment: agreed.
Added links for lists, tuples and zip

Comment: A lot of similar answers so I guess it was a crap shoot as to which got accepted. But adding the links makes this better in my view.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [(1,3),(2,4)]

just_first = [pair[0] for pair in my_list]
```

You can index the values using 2 indices. The index for '1' in your example is [0][0] and the index for '2' is [1][0]

Answer (score 0):

You can still index, the tuples are referred to what's called nested.

As for code, to access them you could write:

```
vals = [(1,3),(2,4)]

val1, val2 = vals[0][0], vals[1][0]
```